# How to disable items from NSMenu for certain views?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I've an app with three views that are presented in the same window.

When the user enters to view 1 I want that some items of the Main Menu to be enabled, when enters to view 2 other items and when enter to view 3 I want all items to be disabled.

How can I do this?

Comment: Generally to achieve something is the result of trying something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the docs for the informal protocol `NSMenuValidation`: It says: *This informal protocol allows your application to update the enabled or disabled status of an `NSMenuItem` object. It declares only one method, `validateMenuItem`:* So in the target object of your MenuItem you have to implement:

```
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem
{
   // what is the item?
   NSLog( @"validate %@", [menuItem title] );   // useful for testing
   // return something like this:
   if( [ [menuItem title] isEqualToString:@"Show something"] ){
       return ! [view3 userIsHere];
   }
   return YES;
}
```

In the documentation for this method you find another example.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the <*NSMenuItemValidation*> has become a formal protocol since macOS 10.14+. On Apple Developer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitemvalidation/3005191-validatemenuitem?language=objc the documentation states the optional instance method *validateMenuItem* as being macOS 10.0-11.0 deprecated (as part of an informal protocol).

However, according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1518160-validatemenuitem the method is now **Required** to implement as  became a formal protocol since macOS 10.14+.

This would mean you will have to conform to the protocol in one of the supported classes such as *NSApplication*, *NSDocument*[*Controller*] or *NSWindow* as listed. As an example, going forward such headers should contain:

```
//Public interface
@interface MyDocument : NSDocument<NSMenuItemValidation>

@end
```

Assuming Objective-C, a generic implementation on macOS could adopt <*NSUserInterfaceValidations*, *NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem*> and implement the corresponding alternative method like:

```
- (BOOL)validateUserInterfaceItem:(NSMenuItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"MenuController validateUserInterfaceItem: title=%@ [%@]", [item title], item.keyEquivalent);
    if ([item action] == @selector(closeFile:)) {//Only match actions that need disabling
        if (!isFileOpen) {//If app state is already file closed
            return NO;//Disable this specific menu item "Close"
        }
    }

    return YES;//Defaults to user interface item enabled
};
```

More information about **Enabling Menu Items** can be found under  [Application Menu and Pop-up List Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html).